# Routing same name controllers and different areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have 2 same name controllers, `ShopController`, one is a `normal` controller (basically where you usually put them), and the other one is in an area called `Admin`.

Here are my routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("Shop", "shop/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Shop", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new[] { "CMS.Controllers" });
routes.MapRoute("CategoriesrPartial", "Admin/Shop/CategoriesNavPartial", new { controller = "Shop", action = "CategoriesNavPartial" }, new[] { "CMS.Areas.Admin.Controllers" });
```

The bottom is supposed to be connected to the `Admin` area one, and the top one to the regular one.

I tried adding namespaces based on another answer here on SO but they don't make a difference, even if I put some gibberish in it does not make a difference.

How can I have these routes refer to exact controllers I want?

Comment: why do you even need the second route registration ? the route pattern matches the route convention (`areaname/controllername/actionmethod`)

Comment: Because I am not following the route convention from the beginning, so each new controller needs a new route.

Comment: I would suggest adding an ` area = "Admin"` to your defaults for the admin route. Or include this in your `AdminAreaRegistration.cs` file

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

the order when you add routes to the route collection is significant, the engine will look into that route collection and the first that will match that route will be picked as the winner.

if your first route matches, means that it start with the word **shop** then it will hit the controller Shop, if not it will continue matching the structure over the RouteData collection. There is no need to add the namespaces on this case

```
shop/{action}  -> should start with shop word then you need to specify the action in your anonymous object
```